# WCF service with X509 certificate is unable to get consumed in Java client

Tags: java, c#, wcf, x509certificate, basichttpbinding

I have developed a service in WCF with x509 certifcate security and deployed on UAT. My .net client is able to consume the service and also getting response from the service.

However when I consume the same service in Java, then I get the below error:
Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties. This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

My Service Config is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\web_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\web_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>


  <system.serviceModel>

 <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logKnownPii="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing propagateActivity="true" activityTracing="true"
        messageFlowTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>

  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceCredentials>
             <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck"  />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="myuatdomain.com"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  httpsGetEnabled="true"        
       httpsGetUrl="https://myuatdomain.com:7443/IR/Transaction.svc/mex"   />

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CertBind" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"                
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding"  scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <services>
            <service name="InwardRemittanceService.Transaction">
                <endpoint name="basic" address="https://myuatdomain.com:7443/IR/Transaction.svc/mex"  
        binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IRService.ITransaction" bindingConfiguration="CertBind" >
         <identity>
            <dns value="myuatdomain.com"/>
            <certificateReference findValue="myuatdomain.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" 
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </identity>
        </endpoint>
            </service>
     </services>  
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should post the client code, too.

Comment: Are your certificates self signed? The best way to make sure that your service is compatible to be consumed by a Java client is to use SOAP UI tools to consume your WCF service. If it works from SOAPUI then it should pretty much work with a Java Client. Make sure that your Java client is setting the appropriate authentication mechanism to be similar to BasicHttpBinding with Https (SSL) and if self signed certificates are used then you will have to bypass the ServerCertificateValidationCallback on client